# How to remove text in a list at each index

Tags: python, list, indexing, text, numbers

I have a list similar to:

```
['42344 xxxxxx xxxx 12','31232 zzzzzz xxxxx 15','3111 yyyyyy aaaaaa 34']
```

I need to modify the list to remove the first numbers only and display the list so that after each comma there is a new line. The expected output would be:

```
xxxxxx xxxx 12
zzzzzz xxxxx 15
yyyyyy aaaaaa 34
```

I tried many codes but I'm lost now and don't know how to arrive to my desired output.

Comment: "I tried many codes" - what exactly have you tried? What exactly didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be the `str.split` on whitespace, then slice off the first element, and `join` back together.

```
data = ['42344 xxxxxx xxxx 12','31232 zzzzzz xxxxx 15','3111 yyyyyy aaaaaa 34']
for line in data:
    print(' '.join(line.split()[1:]))
```

Output

```
xxxxxx xxxx 12
zzzzzz xxxxx 15
yyyyyy aaaaaa 34
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you so much! I honestly don't know how I did not think of that haha

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this in one line with list comprehension :

```
>>> new_list = [' '.join(i.split()[1:]) for i in old_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['42344 xxxxxx xxxx 12','31232 zzzzzz xxxxx 15','3111 yyyyyy aaaaaa 34']

#the symbols that should be removed before you reach the one you need
what_should_be_removed = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ' ']  

i = 0
for string in my_list: #checking each element in my_list
    for char in string:  #checking each character in the phrase
        if char in what_should_be_removed:
            i += 1  
        else:
            print(string[i:]) #slicing the string
            i = 0
            break
```